# How to connect flutter web to mysql

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I run my flutter app in 2 emulators, android and chrome. In android emulator my app showed mysql data but flutter web didn't show the data in chrome emulator.

Any help?

Comment: Flutter Web runs in the user's browser - where it's sandboxed (so it doesn't have access to network IO besides websockets and `fetch`, not real TCP sockets, so you'll need to use an intermediary web-service.

Comment: Hi Dai.. thanks for your response. can you tell me more about intermediary web-service? when my other apps connected to firebase database, it showed the data in chrome emulator. Any solution to connect between flutter web and mysql?

Comment: Firebase is hosted and operated by Google and exposes data via a web-service, it isn't an actual direct database-server connection. You'll need to essentially build your own Firebase-like web-service - you can build one quickly if you use OData or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin are you using to access SQL data? If you're using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), it [doesn't have support for web](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/570#issuecomment-756064208). Note that sqflite are commonly used for local storage. If you're looking for other end-users to access the same database as well, you might want to consider looking into other solutions like [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). Otherwise, you can try using [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) plugin - which has SQL support for mobile and web.